# filedrop.js rename file using hidden field

Tags: jquery, .net, razor, filedrop.js

I am using filedrop.js to upload files (.net mvc razor).

I want to rename the file based on a hidden form field value upon file upload.

There is a rename function, but I don't know how to pass the new name, field value to it.

Here is the code on the page:

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/filedrop.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#dropSection").filedrop({
                fallback_id: 'btnUpload',
                fallback_dropzoneClick: true,
                url: '@Url.Action("Upload")',
                //allowedfiletypes: ['image/jpeg', 'image/png', 'image/gif', 'application/pdf', 'application/doc'],
                allowedfileextensions: ['.ics', '.docx', '.pdf', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.png', '.gif'],
                paramname: 'fileData',
                maxfiles: 25, //Maximum Number of Files allowed at a time.
                maxfilesize: 2, //Maximum File Size in MB.
                dragOver: function () {
                    $('#dropSection').addClass('active');
                },
                dragLeave: function () {
                    $('#dropSection').removeClass('active');
                },
                drop: function () {
                    $('#dropSection').removeClass('active');
                },
                uploadFinished: function (i, file, response, time) {
                    $('#uploadedFiles').append(file.name + '<br />')
                },
                afterAll: function (e) {
                    //To do some task after all uploads done.
                }
            })
        })
    </script>
    }
```